# Cisco 48 port switch template diagram

Tags: cisco, documentation

We have just taken delivery of a 'mature' 48 port switch for testing, deployment and general skulduggery.  Since we are going to be constantly mucking around with the patching we need a diagram so we know which port is on what VLAN.

Has anybody seen such a template/diagram/key on their internet travels?  We were hoping for something a bit more stylish than two rows of 24 in Excel - as befits a classy bit of network kit such as this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco has a nice collection of Visio *"Stencils"* at https://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/prod_visio_icon_list.html

Answer (score 2):

Last time I needed something like that, 48 lines with two columns (port number, intended use/VLAN) was my preferred solution. It was taped inside the door to the cabinet with the switch, with the text on the "inside". Not pretty, but actually surprisingly tech-friendly. When you needed to change something, do the config change and then amend the paper using a pen. Once in a while, take the paper down and generate a clean copy.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and one I will be putting in place immediately on our new office fit out. With appropriate punishment for not filling it in!

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, but what the hey.

More and more, I find my non-physical diagrams use the "white box" model. In other words, I abstract everything away. If I've got a 48 port switch, then I've got a big white box with 48 smaller boxes in it, numbered.

The pictures are pretty, but they just distract me from the purpose, which is to represent the logical state of a device.

Answer (score 0):

You want [VisioCafe](http://www.visiocafe.com)